# Renaming X-axis variables to separate current month data and previous month data

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hi guys I have hospital data that looks like this;

```
hospitals <- c('Johnd Hospital','Johnd Hospital','Jolie Hope Hospital','Jolie Hope Hospital','Hope Hospital','Hope Hospital')
variables <- c('temperature', 'temperature', 'pulse rate','pulse rate', 'resp rate', 'resp rate')
score <- c(92,82,63,78, 23, 59)
months <- c('october', 'september', 'october', 'september', 'october', 'september')

datat <- data.frame(hospitals, variables, score, months)

datat$colour <- ifelse(datat$score >=90, "seagreen3", 
                           ifelse(datat$score > 80 & datat$score <= 89, "gold1",
                                  ifelse(datat$score > 60 & datat$score <= 79, "plum2", "red3")))
#performance scores
datat$perfomance <- ifelse(as.numeric(datat$score) >=90, "Excellent Perfomance (>=90)%", 
                               ifelse(as.numeric(datat$score) >= 80 & as.numeric(datat$score) <= 89, "Good Perfomance (80-89)%",
                                      ifelse(as.numeric(datat$score) > 60 & as.numeric(datat$score) <= 79, "Some Perfomance (60-79)%", "Poor Perfomance (<60)%")))

nam = c("Good Perfomance (80-89)%", "Some Perfomance (60-79)%", "Poor Perfomance (<60)%", "Excellent Perfomance (>=90)%")
grays = c("gold1", "plum2", "red3", "seagreen3")

my_color <- setNames(grays, nam)
my_color
```

Now this data I want to plot perfomance of variables for current month and previous month. Until now I am able to visualize a dodge bar graph for variable score for current month and last month. an example is a variable like temperature which I have two bars for this month and last month.
Here  is how I visualized

```
myplott <- function(datat, hospital) {
  
  print(paste0("Plot for hospital: ", hospital))
  
  p <- ggplot(datat%>% filter(hospitals == hospital), 
              aes(x = variables, y = as.numeric(score))) +
    #facet_grid(cols = vars(Group), scales = "free", space = "free") +
    geom_bar(position = "dodge2", stat = "identity") +
    theme_bw() +
    ylab("Percentage %") +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(-10, 100, by = 10)) +
    ggtitle(hospital) +
    labs(caption = "Please note; -5 (red paint below 0) indicates 0% documentation for that indicator") +
    ### use manual color here
    scale_fill_manual(values = my_color) +
    
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 13, hjust = 1, angle = 45)) +
    geom_hline(yintercept = 90, linetype = "dashed", color = "black", size = 0.5) +
    geom_hline(yintercept = 80, linetype = "dashed", color = "black", size = 0.5) +
    geom_hline(yintercept = 60, linetype = "dashed", color = "black", size = 0.5) +
    geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed", color = "black", size = 0.5) +
    #geom_text(aes(label = value), vjust = 0, color = "black", size = 2.8) +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(face = "bold", hjust = 0.5, size = 20), legend.position = "top") +
    #theme(plot.subtitle.title = element_text('Admission and during admission vitals monitored')) +
    theme(legend.title = element_blank())
  
  return(p)
  
}
myplott(comb.data, "Jolie Hope Hospital")
```

My struggle now is how to name bars on the X-axis so that a person can know the bar for previous month and current month, like naming *temperature* as *temperature(october)* and *temperature (november)*. End result is renaming variable scores for current month and previous month on X-axis.If anyone knows how I can name the bars on X-axis, kindly help. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way can be using `interaction()`:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Function
myplott <- function(datat, hospital) {
  
  print(paste0("Plot for hospital: ", hospital))
  
  p <- ggplot(datat%>% filter(hospitals == hospital), 
              aes(x = interaction(variables,months), y = as.numeric(score))) +
    #facet_grid(cols = vars(Group), scales = "free", space = "free") +
    geom_bar(position = "dodge2", stat = "identity") +
    theme_bw() +
    ylab("Percentage %") +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(-10, 100, by = 10)) +
    ggtitle(hospital) +
    labs(caption = "Please note; -5 (red paint below 0) indicates 0% documentation for that indicator") +
    ### use manual color here
    scale_fill_manual(values = my_color) +
    #geom_text(aes(label=months),position = position_dodge2(0.9),vjust=-0.5)+
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 13, hjust = 1, angle = 45)) +
    geom_hline(yintercept = 90, linetype = "dashed", color = "black", size = 0.5) +
    geom_hline(yintercept = 80, linetype = "dashed", color = "black", size = 0.5) +
    geom_hline(yintercept = 60, linetype = "dashed", color = "black", size = 0.5) +
    geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed", color = "black", size = 0.5) +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(face = "bold", hjust = 0.5, size = 20), legend.position = "top") +
    #theme(plot.subtitle.title = element_text('Admission and during admission vitals monitored')) +
    theme(legend.title = element_blank())+
    xlab('')
  
  return(p)
  
}
#Apply
myplott(datat, "Jolie Hope Hospital")
```

Output:

[image]

Or from my perspective, most elegant:

```
#Function 2
myplott <- function(datat, hospital) {
  
  print(paste0("Plot for hospital: ", hospital))
  
  p <- ggplot(datat%>% filter(hospitals == hospital), 
              aes(x = variables, y = as.numeric(score))) +
    #facet_grid(cols = vars(Group), scales = "free", space = "free") +
    geom_bar(position = "dodge2", stat = "identity") +
    theme_bw() +
    ylab("Percentage %") +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(-10, 100, by = 10)) +
    ggtitle(hospital) +
    labs(caption = "Please note; -5 (red paint below 0) indicates 0% documentation for that indicator") +
    ### use manual color here
    scale_fill_manual(values = my_color) +
    geom_text(aes(label=months),position = position_dodge2(0.9),vjust=-0.5)+
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 13, hjust = 1, angle = 45)) +
    geom_hline(yintercept = 90, linetype = "dashed", color = "black", size = 0.5) +
    geom_hline(yintercept = 80, linetype = "dashed", color = "black", size = 0.5) +
    geom_hline(yintercept = 60, linetype = "dashed", color = "black", size = 0.5) +
    geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed", color = "black", size = 0.5) +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(face = "bold", hjust = 0.5, size = 20), legend.position = "top") +
    #theme(plot.subtitle.title = element_text('Admission and during admission vitals monitored')) +
    theme(legend.title = element_blank())+
    xlab('')
  
  return(p)
  
}
#Apply
myplott(datat, "Jolie Hope Hospital")
```

Output:

[image]

**Update:**

```
#Function 3
myplott <- function(datat, hospital) {
  
  print(paste0("Plot for hospital: ", hospital))
  
  p <- ggplot(datat%>% filter(hospitals == hospital), 
              aes(x = variables, y = as.numeric(score),fill=months)) +
    #facet_grid(cols = vars(Group), scales = "free", space = "free") +
    geom_bar(position = "dodge2", stat = "identity") +
    theme_bw() +
    ylab("Percentage %") +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(-10, 100, by = 10)) +
    ggtitle(hospital) +
    labs(caption = "Please note; -5 (red paint below 0) indicates 0% documentation for that indicator") +
    ### use manual color here
    #scale_fill_manual(values = my_color) +
    # geom_text(aes(label=months),position = position_dodge2(0.9),vjust=-0.5)+
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 13, hjust = 1, angle = 45)) +
    geom_hline(yintercept = 90, linetype = "dashed", color = "black", size = 0.5) +
    geom_hline(yintercept = 80, linetype = "dashed", color = "black", size = 0.5) +
    geom_hline(yintercept = 60, linetype = "dashed", color = "black", size = 0.5) +
    geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed", color = "black", size = 0.5) +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(face = "bold", hjust = 0.5, size = 20), legend.position = "top") +
    #theme(plot.subtitle.title = element_text('Admission and during admission vitals monitored')) +
    theme(legend.title = element_blank())+
    xlab('')
  
  return(p)
  
}
#Apply
myplott(datat, "Jolie Hope Hospital")
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this...I would love to use *interaction* but I notice it arranges the names alphabetically, could it be possible that a variable with two bars be next to each other for the sake of comparisons?

Comment: @LivingstoneM I can modify the code to keep bars but filling by month? Would you agree with that?

Comment: @LivingstoneM I have added an update, let me know if you feel comfortable with that